# The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: powershell, posh-git

Installing posh-git - see here https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git

If I've just installed PsGet installed then running:

```
Install-Module posh-git
```

works fine.

But if I close and re-launch Powershell then I get:

```
The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

when I try and run it.

Any idea why?

Comment: It is installed for that session only it seems. Perhaps you just need to add that code into your [PowerShell profile](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles.aspx).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828756/the-term-install-module-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet)

Answer (score 1):

Once the module has been installed, you typically use Import-Module to reload it e.g.:

```
Import-Module posh-git
```

That said, later versions of PowerShell (V3 and above) will autoload the module if you attempt to execute a command from that module.  This does assume that PowerShell can discover the command in the posh-git module.