# The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, posh-git

I am following the directions to install [poshgit](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git).  In doing so I ran:

`Install-Module posh-git`

Error:

> The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and t
>   ry again.

I ran `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`: result = `2.0.-1.-1`

Is `Install-Module` an addon?  How can I run this command?

Answer (score 9):

Do you have `PsGet` installed? That's the [Installing via PsGet](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git#installing-via-psget) section.

The section after that is the [manual instructions](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git#installing-manual):

> 1. Verify you have PowerShell 2.0 or better with $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
> 2. Verify execution of scripts is allowed with `Get-ExecutionPolicy` (should be `RemoteSigned` or `Unrestricted`). If scripts are not enabled,
>      run PowerShell as Administrator and call `Set-ExecutionPolicy
>      RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser -Confirm`.
> 3. Verify that git can be run from PowerShell. If the command is not found, you will need to add a git alias or add
>      `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Git\cmd` (or `%ProgramFiles%\Git\cmd` if you're still
>      on 32-bit) to your PATH environment variable.
> 4. Clone the posh-git repository to your local machine.
> 5. From the posh-git repository directory, run `.\install.ps1`.
> 6. Enjoy!

Comment: The names PSGet and poshgit are so close I read them as the same product.  Woops

Comment: The question was about Install-Module being unrecognized commandlet

Comment: install-module is part of PowerShellGet module which is available from the PowerShell Gallery.
Installing from PowerShell Gallery requires the latest version of the PoweShellGet module which is available in 
- Windows 10, in Windows Management Frameowork 5.0, or in the MSI-based installer(for Powershell 3 and 4). Since I've got PS4, I went and installed via the MSI (PackageManagement PowerShell Modules Preview - March 2016)

Comment: @Abhijit Yes, which is why the first part of my answer was "Do you have `PsGet` installed?" as that would be why `Import-Module` might not be available. Information about Windows 10 is useful but post-dates this answer by at least three months.

Comment: @EtanReisner My apologies. I reached this post when I had problem getting Install-Module to run and I could resolve that by installing PackageManagement PowerShell Modules MSI package (I'm still on PS 4). I wasn't aware of PsGet (as against PowerShellGet from Microsoft).

Comment: make sure you run the powershell or powershell ISE as admin

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but with `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` = 4.0. Apparently `Install-Module` is part of PS v5.

I downloaded PS 5 from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616

I'm still on Win 8.1 x64 so I chose `Win8.1AndW2K12R2-KB3191564-x64.msu` but pick the file appropriate for your environment.

Reboot, start PS and retry the `Install-Module` command.