# Missing git support, install posh-git with 'Install-Module posh-git' and restart cmder

Tags: git, powershell, cmder

I want to work with git, from the cmder powershell.

### Errors

Cmder prints out the following error:

> Missing git support, install posh-git with 'Install-Module posh-git' and restart cmder

If I run the `Install-Module posh-git` cmder prints out the next error:

> - Install-Module <<<<  posh-git
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Install-Module:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

### Things I have done/tried

- Installed 'Git for Windows'
- Replaced the files in `cmder/vendor/git-for-windows` with the installed files from 'Git for Windows'
- Tried solutions from [git not properly setup in v1.2 #513](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/513) and [Path issues on startup #487](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/487)
- Installed posh-git manually

### Problem

My git commands are working, but not showing me the branch I am working on.

So how can I fix this?

Comment: "Installed posh-git manually" <-- What did you do here?

Comment: Also, what version of PowerShell are you running?  `Install-Module` requires 3.0 or later.

Comment: I followed the Installing (manual) guide for posh git here: [link](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git)
My PowerShell Version is Version 2.0 -> so I will try to update Powershell and run that command `Install-Module posh-git` again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828756/the-term-install-module-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet)

Comment: Your CommandNotFoundException is because `Install-Module` requires Powershell 3.0, or `PSGet` to be installed.  However, the manual install should work.  Verify that the file `posh-git.psm1` is located somewhere in `$env:PSModulePath`.

Comment: Also, on a whim, try restarting PowerShell after running `install.ps1`, if you haven't already.  Then run `Import-Module posh-git`

Comment: I updated my Powershell and run the commend again, now it works just fine. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your CommandNotFoundException is because `Install-Module` requires Powershell 3.0, or `PSGet` to be installed.  However, the manual install should work.

Verify that the file `posh-git.psm1` is located somewhere in `$env:PSModulePath`.  Then restart PowerShell and run `Import-Module posh-git`.  This should force it to find the module.

Answer (score 22):

This answer is for when posh-git is not wanted. posh-git can introduce  significant delays to the prompt's display.

In the cmder profile (\vendor\profile.ps1) file, comment out the following lines in the function "checkGit".

```
function checkGit($Path) {
    #if (Test-Path -Path (Join-Path $Path '.git')) {
    #    $gitLoaded = Import-Git $gitLoaded
    #    Write-VcsStatus
    #    return
    #}
```

Note: Sorry, this answer doesn't answer the original request to see the current branch. I think that this solution may be a better fit for some people.

**Update:**

Here's a better solution that won't need to be reapplied every time that cmder is updated:

Add the following function to \config\user_profile.ps1 (the full path for my chocolatey installation file is c:\tools\cmdermini\config\user_profile.ps1):

`function checkGit() {}`

Comment: Yes, this is the answer I'm looking for. If you could change your code block  from `<quote>` to `<code>` it would be better. You can do this by adding 4 space before each line of code. And for convenience, use `<# ... #>`(powershell style comment block) instead of `#`.

Comment: THANKYOU! This has been driving me nuts for months.

Comment: Instead of disabling posh-git altogether, you can also `$GitPromptSettings.EnableFileStatus = $false` to turn off the `git status` check for every prompt without losing most tab expansion.